# Hide all fields in a particurlar section/fieldset

Tags: jquery

I am working on a larger project and came up with an idea, that I can't seem to get working using jquery.  Client has web form.  A dropdown field is on the form, that will make certain sections/fieidset display and disappear upon selection.  I got that going, but then the client wants to have certain fields within those sections display or not based on the type selected from the dropdown.

My idea - I want to hide all the fields within a section is there a way to say hide everything in this section except.

so for example:

```
<fieldset name="Group1" id="sectionOne">
                <legend>Section 1</legend>
                <input id="txt_123" type="text" />
                <input id="txt_124" type="text" />
                <input id="txt_125" type="text" />
                <input id="txt_125" type="text" />
                <input id="txt_126" type="text" />
            </fieldset>
</body>
```

if i want to say hide everything in #sectionOne. Then later I want to to say hide everything in #sectionOne except....

remember I will have any number of sections with any number of fields, so I want a shorter way than just lines of `$(#txt_123).hide();/$(#txt_124).show();`

I just really want a clean way of say hide everything in this section except......

Comment: I want to have the mean to say "hide all the fields in #sectionOne except #text_124 and #txt_126.  or show all the fields, or hide everything except one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
$("fieldset#sectionOne input").hide();
```

About except option,
I think its better to select which elements to hide by applying a common class to all the elements that you want to hide.

Comment: Prem - I think I need to go this route, but it doesn't appear to be working for me.  The above is just saying --hide all the input type fields that are in the fieldset with the id of sectionOne?

Answer (score 1):

Why not hide the section itself?

```
$('#sectionOne').slideUp();
```

if you really want to hide the contents, use

```
$('#sectionOne legend,input,select,textarea').slideUp();
```

Comment: but I will need to display certain fields and hide others.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to apply a class to the inputs.

```
$("fieldset").find("input").each(function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass("hidden") ...
});
```

You can also add some additional functionality ... note : not sure how you plan to show things...

```
$("fieldset").click(function() {
  $(this).find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() { $(this).removeClass("hidden") });
  });
});
```

etc etc...

Answer (score 0):

add a class to that inputs ,

```
<input class ='inputs'>
```

with jquery : 
 $(".inputs").hide();

Comment: class attribute is very useful for such needs